# Подсчёт в масиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Прошу помощи, мозг кипит.
Есть масив с маршрутом и промежуточными остановками [napravlenie]
А в нем еще масивы с пунтом отправления [ot] пунтом прибытия [do] и количеством забранированых мест [person]

```
Array (
 [napravlenie] => ko-od-ki-che
 [0] => Array ( [ot] => ko [do] => ki [person] => 2 )
 [1] => Array ( [ot] => od [do] => ki [person] => 2 )
 [2] => Array ( [ot] => od [do] => ki [person] => 2 )
 [3] => Array ( [ot] => od [do] => che [person] => 1 )
 [4] => Array ( [ot] => ki [do] => che [person] => 1 ) 
)
```

Задача пощитать количество занятых мест до каждого пункта. Нужно учитывать [ot] => od [do] => che проходит через ki и сответственно от od-ki место тоже занято

Comment: А как вы узнали, что do->che проходит через ki?

Comment: И не совсем понятен массив что вы привели, можете вывести массив как есть? var_dump или print_r?

Comment: [napravlenie] => ko-od-ki-che  ko отправление. che  прибытие.  а -od-ki- поочередные промежуточные.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TourCapacitor
{
    protected $delta = [];

    /**
     * @param array route Маршрут с идентификаторами остановок 
     */
    public function __construct(array $route)
    {
        foreach ($route as $row) {
            $this->delta[$row] = null;
        }
    }

    public function add($itemId)
    {
        if ($this->delta[$itemId]) {
            $this->delta[$itemId] += 1;
        } else {
            $this->delta[$itemId] = 1;
        }
    }

    public function remove($itemId)
    {
        if ($this->delta[$itemId]) {
            $this->delta[$itemId] -= 1;
        } else {
            $this->delta[$itemId] = -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCapacities()
    {
        $result = [];

        if (!$this->delta) {
            return $result;
        }

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->delta as $key => $value) {
            if ($value === null) {
                continue;
            }

            // создаём новую остановку
            $result[$i] = ['key' => $key, 'value' => $value];
            // если есть предыдущая остановка, добавляем её значение
            if ($i > 0) {
                $result[$i]['value'] += $result[$i - 1]['value'];
            }

            $i++;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Считаем

```
$capacity = new TourCapacitor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
// $orders - массив с заказами. stationFrom - остановка посадки. stationTo - остановка высадки
foreach ($orders as $row) {
    $capacity->add($row['stationFrom']);
    $capacity->remove($row['stationTo']);
}
var_dump($capacity->getCapacities());
```

Answer (score 0):

То что я искал.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$A = array(
    'napravlenie' => 'ko-od-ki-che',
    0 => array('ot' => 'ko', 'do' => 'ki',  'person' => 2),
    1 => array('ot' => 'od', 'do' => 'ki',  'person' => 2),
    2 => array('ot' => 'od', 'do' => 'ki',  'person' => 2),
    3 => array('ot' => 'od', 'do' => 'che', 'person' => 1),
    4 => array('ot' => 'ki', 'do' => 'che', 'person' => 1)
);
# ($A[1] == $A[2]) -->>  $A[real][person] = $A[1][person] + $A[2][person] ...?
echo '<xmp>';
var_dump($A);
echo "---------------------\n\n";

$SEQ = explode('-', $A['napravlenie']);
$CUR_VAL = 0;
while (($OT = current($SEQ)) && $DO = next($SEQ)){
    for ($x=0; $x<count($A)-1; ++$x){
            if ($A[$x]['ot'] == $OT) $CUR_VAL += $A[$x]['person'];
        elseif( $A[$x]['do'] == $OT) $CUR_VAL -= $A[$x]['person'];
    }
    echo "$OT-$DO => $CUR_VAL\n";
}

echo '</xmp>';
```

Comment: Ваш алгоритм покажет сколько человек вошло - вышло на каждой остановке. Но не покажет количество свободных (занятых мест).

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/qFGkD8xkAs8FqW1cqOR9hkq6Mw994q  На скрине видно каких цифер добиваюсь. это количество занятых мест. То есть до Одессы тоже будет занято место если пассажир проезжает ее транзитом. Сам не особо понимаю как но мой пример считает правильно